# Why str([1]) = [1] and not "1" in python

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

```
str([1]) = [1]
```

If we apply type conversion on the `str([1])`, why don't we get the answer = `"1"`.

Comment: If you write ``string([1])`` all you get is ``NameError: name 'string' is not defined``. And the string representation of a list does include the brackets, unless you subclass ``list`` and override ``__str__``.

Comment: it should be str([1]) to make string conversion in Python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first of all use str() in python ;)
str cast the parameter you give into a string. So when the parameter is an array, it returns you "[1]". You can see the type of the result with type(param), it'll be a string and if you print res[0] it'll give you "["
If you wanna get ride of the [] you can use the code bellow for example :

```s
print(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no type conversion here. `str` is a builtin function that takes any object, and produces a string representation of it (typically using the `__str__` method of the object).

Here, the argument to `str` is a list `[1]`, and the `__str__` method of list converts its elements to strings (using `repr`), joins them with commas, and surrounds them with square brackets `[]`.